# Salesforce Reports and Dashboard for Customer Community

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

### In my **digital Experience (Cloud Community)**

I am trying to access Reports and Dashboard through the User which is having Licence ***'Customer Community'*** and by using this Licence i have created one Profile.
In that profile, i have given tab access to Repots and Dashboards.
In this case, the client cannot see the dashboards or even the reports.
So how can I resolve this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: This isn't coding related, you'll get more admin-focused help at dedicated salesforce.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5 says "Customer Community" doesn't have access to Reports. Do you have any "Customer Community Plus"?

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response, 
Yes I tried with "Customer Community Plus" License, it's the same problem. I can't see any reports or dashborad